# Bootstrap popover on injected html button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have injected a button like this:

```
$(panelBody).append('<input type="button" id="pink" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="SWIFT" /> ');
```

but can't get a Bootstrap 3.0 Popover to render next to it when I click. Tried this inside $document.ready():

```
$(document).on('popover', '#pink', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log('clonk');
});
```

but nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Does console return any errors? Does the event handler run in firebug debug?

Comment: Where do you call the popover method?

Comment: @undefined I'm calling it as the first parameter of $(document).on

Comment: it's not calling, you are listening to an event that isn't fired in your code. also it seems bootstrap 3 has changed the name of the events http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/, `eventName.bs.methodName`.

Comment: I don't really know bootstrap at all but perhaps your injection is too late so the new button does not have the popover attached to it so it never fires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now use the `selector` option when creating dynamic popovers:

```
$(panelBody).append('<input type="button" id="pink" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="SWIFT" rel="popover" title="A Title" data-content="This is the content of the popover" />');

$('body').popover({
                    selector: '[rel=popover]'
});

$(document).on('show.bs.popover', function(e) {
    console.log('clonk');
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/kYCJF/)